# Image post via API not working with latest LinkedIn API

Tags: node.js, next.js, linkedin-api

I'm able to post a Text only Post, for some reason the Image Post is not working. I'm getting no errors as well.

I'm following the official API documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/images-api?view=li-lms-2023-06&tabs=http#schema

The response doesn't contain `x-linkedin-id` as mentioned in documentation.

Here is my Next.js backend code:

```
import dbConnect from "../../../lib/dbConnect";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
import formidable from "formidable";
const fs = require("fs").promises;


export const config = {
  api: { bodyParser: false },
};


export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { method } = req;

  await dbConnect();

  switch (method) {

    case "POST":
      try {
        const session = await getSession({ req });


        if (!session || !session.accessToken) {
          console.error("No session or accessToken found.");
          return res.status(401).json({ error: "Not authorized" });
        }

        const accessToken = session.accessToken;
        console.log("accessToken>>>", accessToken);

        const linkedinId = "myLinkedInID";
       
         const data = await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
           const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
           form.uploadDir = "/tmp";
           form.keepExtensions = true;
           form.multiples = true;

           form.parse(req, async function (err, fields, files) {
             if (err) return reject(err);
             resolve({ fields, files });
           });
         });
        
        req.body = data.fields;

        let body = undefined
        // console.log("Frontend>>>", req.body);
        const fileArray = Object.values(data.files);

        switch (req.body.type) {
          case "text":
            body = createTextPost(req.body.content, linkedinId);
            break;

          case "singleImage":

             const tempAsset = await uploadFileToLinkedIn(
               fileArray[0],
               accessToken,
               "image",
               linkedinId
             );
            
            
            body = createSingleImagePost(req.body.content, tempAsset, linkedinId);

            break; 
          

          default:
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid content type" });
        }
        
     const url = "https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts";

     const response = await fetch(url, {
       method: "POST",
       headers: {
         Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
         "Content-Type": "application/json",
         "X-Restli-Protocol-Version": "2.0.0",
         "LinkedIn-Version": "202307",
       },
       body: JSON.stringify(body),
     });
 
     console.log("Status>>>>", response.ok);
     if (response.ok) {
       // Extract the x-linkedin-id from the headers
       console.log("headers>>>>", response.headers);

       const linkedinId = response.headers.get("x-linkedin-id");
       console.log("x-linkedin-id>>>>", linkedinId);

       if (response.bodyUsed) {
         const data = await response.json();
         console.error("data>>>>", data);
       }
     } else {
       // Handle non-OK responses
       const text = await response.text();
      //  console.error("Error response>>>>", text);
     }

     res.status(200).json({ success: true });

        
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("LinkedIn Error", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
      }

      break;
  
  }

  function createTextPost(content, linkedinId) {
    return {
      author: `urn:li:person:${linkedinId}`,
      commentary: content,
      visibility: "PUBLIC",
      distribution: {
        feedDistribution: "MAIN_FEED",
        targetEntities: [],
        thirdPartyDistributionChannels: [],
      },
      lifecycleState: "PUBLISHED",
      isReshareDisabledByAuthor: false,
    };
  }

  function createSingleImagePost(content, media, linkedinId) {
    // Assuming media is a URL or URI to the media asset. Adjust based on actual usage
    return {
      author: `urn:li:person:${linkedinId}`,
      commentary: content,
      visibility: "PUBLIC",
      distribution: {
        feedDistribution: "MAIN_FEED",
        targetEntities: [],
        thirdPartyDistributionChannels: [],
      },
      content: {
        media: {
          altText: "testing for alt tags",
          id: media,
        },
      },
      lifecycleState: "PUBLISHED",
      isReshareDisabledByAuthor: false,
    };
    
  }

  

  async function registerUpload(accessToken, owner, fileSize, mediaType) {
    const registerUrl =
      "https://api.linkedin.com/rest/images?action=initializeUpload";    

    
    const body = {
      initializeUploadRequest: {
        owner: owner,
      },
    };

    const response = await fetch(registerUrl, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-Restli-Protocol-Version": "2.0.0",
        "LinkedIn-Version": "202307",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    });

   if (!response.ok) {
     response
       .text()
       .then((data) => {
         console.error("Failed to register:", data);
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.error("Error parsing response:", error);
       });
     throw new Error("Failed to register upload.");
   }

    return await response.json();
  }

  async function uploadMedia(accessToken, uploadUrl, fileContent, mimetype) {

    var type = "jpg";
    if (mimetype == "image/jpeg") {
      type = "jpeg";
    } else if (mimetype == "image/png" || mimetype == "png") {
      type = "png";
    } else if (mimetype == "image/gif" || mimetype == "gif") {
      type = "gif";
    } else if (mimetype == "image/svg+xml" || mimetype == "svg") {
      type = "svg";
    } else if (mimetype == "application/pdf" || mimetype == "pdf") {
      type = "pdf";
    }

    const obj = {
      data: fileContent,
      mimeType: `application/${mimetype}`,
    };


   try {
     const response = await fetch(uploadUrl, {
       method: "PUT",
       headers: {
         Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
         "X-Restli-Protocol-Version": "2.0.0",
         "LinkedIn-Version": "202307",
         "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data`,
       },
       body: fileContent,
     });


     if (!response.ok) {
       const data = await response.text();
       console.error("Failed to upload media:", data);
       throw new Error("Failed to upload media.");
     }

   } catch (error) {
     console.log("Upload Media Error>>>>", error);
   }

   
  }

  async function uploadFileToLinkedIn(element, accessToken, mediaType, linkedinId) {
    const owner = `urn:li:person:${linkedinId}`;

    const fileSize = element.size;

    let fileContent = await fs.readFile(element.filepath);

    let type = element.mimetype.split("/")[1];

    const registerResponse = await registerUpload(
      accessToken,
      owner,
      fileSize,
      mediaType
    );
    const uploadUrl = registerResponse.value.uploadUrl;
    
    const asset = registerResponse.value.image;

    try {
      
      await uploadMedia(accessToken, uploadUrl, fileContent, type);

    } catch (error) {
      
      console.log("Upload Media FUnction>>>>", error);
    }

    return asset; // This asset can be used in the LinkedIn post creation
  }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This error might be because the 'media' object in the createSingleImagePost function is not properly formed. The LinkedIn API expects an array of 'media' objects.

In your createSingleImagePost function, you are passing an object directly to 'media' like this:

```
content: {
  media: {
    altText: "testing for alt tags",
    id: media,
  },
},
```

This should be an array instead. Change it to this:

```
content: {
  media: [
    {
      altText: "testing for alt tags",
      id: media,
    },
  ],
},
```

Also, verify the media id being used. Ensure it points to a LinkedIn-registered asset ID in the form of 'urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4D00FE0X'.

Lastly, ensure the image is successfully uploaded and registered with LinkedIn before creating the post. Check the response from the uploadFileToLinkedIn function to ensure you have a valid asset ID.

Comment: Using array is giving error ```{"message":"ERROR :: /content/media/0 :: unrecognized field found but not allowed\nERROR :: /content/media :: record type is not backed by a DataMap\n","status":422}```